# How to remove a layout that was added using addContentView()?

Tags: android

I am adding a layout using `addContentView()`.
How can i remove this layout on a Button click ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming `contentView` is the view that was added via `window.addContentView()`

```
((ViewGroup) contentView.getParent()).removeView(contentView);
```

Comment: how to get contentView if I set contentView with setContentView(R.layout.someLayout)

Answer (score 9):

try it

```
View youAddedView;
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
for (int i = 0; i < rootView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if(rootView.getChildAt(i) == yourAddedView) {
        // do anything here
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing lacking in your answer is rootView.removeViewAt(i); break;

Answer (score 5):

If you already have the reference to the view you can simply just do :

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
rootView.removeView(viewToRemove);
```

Instead of looping through the ViewGroup.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no way of removing a content view that was added with `addContentView()`. The best you can you do is to call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on it, to hide it.

That is why the activity's [onContentChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onContentChanged%28%29) only gets called when the content view is set or added to an activity.

Comment: I am simply doing addContentView(R.layout.test); Then to remove how to use this setVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: You will need to get the root of your layout, and then hide it. Example: set `android:id="@+id/root"` , and in your activity call `findViewById(R.id.root).setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: This is a wrong answer. See the answer by vince. That one explains how you can remove that view (which you claim cannot be removed)

Comment: that's correct @WernerVanBelle . Vince's answer is the correct one, which I didn't know about at the time

Answer (score -1):

you can do two things  over here you can set the visibility to gone on the click event of the button.
OR
you can set the layout parameter to layout width and height to 0dp
It will hide your layout display