# Set content view not working

Tags: java, android, xml

```
public class troopcard extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.troopcard);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.pekkacard:
            setContentView(R.layout.pekkacard);
            break;
        case R.id.dragcard:
            setContentView(R.layout.dragcard);


    }

}
}
```

The question here is why isnt the set content view working?as in the xml isnt opening of which i want. as making a intent then directing to a class then setting content view will take a hell load of time. I thought by directly setting the content view it might work. it isnt. What could be the solution. i really dont want to make a separate class for this as i have **40 + xmls**. so is there a way to directly set content view without having to make a class?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you getting an Exception?

Comment: the xml isnt opening of which i want.

Comment: Can you add log statements below the `setContentView()` calls to verify and make sure that they're being EXECUTED but simply don't do anything?

Comment: Log.e(String.valueOf(TAG), "It's a click ! ");
i added this in one of the cases.

Comment: The log isnt coming in the logcat

Comment: try this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/28085386/4146722

Answer (score 0):

This is not a true programming architecture. If you have more than one layout you should use more than one activity or fragment.

Comment: But if i have 40 layouts. I dont need to make 40 activities. do i?

Comment: use fragment for that dude!!@BlueSlimShady

Comment: OOP approach says us : "Create much class as you need and try to reuse them by inheritance or implementation. ". If you say what do you exactly want to make? Maybe we can help you ...

Comment: I just need to set a different layout on click without actually creating a new class

Comment: For what ? Give an example please.

Comment: Please vote my answer. I answered your question firstly.

Answer (score 0):

Switching on R.id won't work. You are never actually calling

```
setContentView(R.layout.pekkacard);
```

or

```
setContentView(R.layout.dragcard);
```

Try:

```
Override
public void onClick(View v) {

            setContentView(R.layout.pekkacard);

    }
```

to see if it displays the other layout.

Comment: how? on click whatever is in the case should execute right?

Comment: Try setContentView(R.layout.pekkacard); without the condition switch, just to see if it works. See my edited answer.